# Notepad++: Extracting all words from a very long string that contains a set of rounded brackets

Tags: regex, find, notepad++

I have a large .txt file written in German. It is a transcript of many people speaking. When an abbreviate form of a word is used, the correct form of the word is written around it, or inside it, in brackets. I would like to extract, as a list, all such examples that exist in this .txt. I have tried a few Regex but I can't seem to get it to highlight the entire "word".

Any ideas?

Here is a part of the .txt with the words I'd like extracted highlighted:

Ich **hab(e)** am Achtundzwanzigsten achten neunzehnhundertneunzig Geburtstag. Also wenn ich mich beschreiben sollte, dann muss ich sagen freundlich, unkompliziert und bescheiden. Hallo wie gehts **(geht es)** dir. Na was machst **(machst du)** den jetzt **heut(e)**. Und, eh, hm, was noch? **Stör(e)** ich? Ja das **is(t)**, eh, so, **würd(e)** ich das so sagen....

Thanks!

Answer (score 2):

If I well understand your needs, how about:

```
(\w+\(\w+\))| \([\w\s]+\)
```

**Explanation:**

```
The regular expression:

(?-imsx:(\w+\(\w+\))| \([\w\s]+\))

matches as follows:

NODE                     EXPLANATION
----------------------------------------------------------------------
(?-imsx:                 group, but do not capture (case-sensitive)
                         (with ^ and $ matching normally) (with . not
                         matching \n) (matching whitespace and #
                         normally):
----------------------------------------------------------------------
  (                        group and capture to \1:
----------------------------------------------------------------------
    \w+                      word characters (a-z, A-Z, 0-9, _) (1 or
                             more times (matching the most amount
                             possible))
----------------------------------------------------------------------
    \(                       '('
----------------------------------------------------------------------
    \w+                      word characters (a-z, A-Z, 0-9, _) (1 or
                             more times (matching the most amount
                             possible))
----------------------------------------------------------------------
    \)                       ')'
----------------------------------------------------------------------
  )                        end of \1
----------------------------------------------------------------------
 |                        OR
----------------------------------------------------------------------
                           ' '
----------------------------------------------------------------------
  \(                       '('
----------------------------------------------------------------------
  [\w\s]+                  any character of: word characters (a-z, A-
                           Z, 0-9, _), whitespace (\n, \r, \t, \f,
                           and " ") (1 or more times (matching the
                           most amount possible))
----------------------------------------------------------------------
  \)                       ')'
----------------------------------------------------------------------
)                        end of grouping
```

Comment: this does not seem to be working on the sample text provided in Notepad++. I am using v5.9.2

Comment: Is this explanation automatically generated from somewhere?

Comment: @Retsam: Yes, with a Perl module : YAPE::Regex::Explain available at CPAN http://search.cpan.org/~gsullivan/YAPE-Regex-Explain-4.01/Explain.pm

Answer (score 0):

This regular expression finds all the contents between `(` and `)` included and also everything before `(` and its preceeding space character:

```
[^ ]*\([^)]*\)
```

Now to transform your text into a nice list:

- open find/replace dialog (Ctrl-H)
- Find what: `.*?([^ ]*\([^)]*\))`
- Replace with: `\1\n`
- "Regular expression" with "Matches newline" checked
- Press "Replace All" with cursor at the beginning of file (Ctrl-Home)
- Ignore or delete last line

Now you have a nice list of all these words each on separate line.

Comment: but it would not capture something like "freu(sd)ich"

Comment: I dont speak german and that wasnt in original test data, this could be accomplished by adding `[^ ]*` to the end of current regexp. Or `[^\s\.\,\;\?\!]*` like you do to get rid of some other punctuation characters that may be at the end of words.

Answer (score 0):

Notepad++ uses a regex flavor that may not be POSIX compliant, hence does not support word boundaries. (Atleast v5.9.2 does not support it)
Try this regular expression:

```
[^\s]*\([^)]*\)[^\s\.\,\;\?\!]*
```

- `[^\s]*` : detects beginning of a word by not matching any whitespace before a word (tab, space, etc..)
- `\([^)]*\)` : matches the brackets and its content
- `[^\s\.\,\;\?\!]*` : detects ending of a word by not matching any whitespace or possible punctuation symbols.

You can extend this by adding more punctuation marks before or after the word (like quotes).
Successfully tested this on Notepad++ v5.9.2 on your sample text.